# Display first ten values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, count

I'm trying to display the first 10 items from an array as list items and then write some logic that includes a button to display the rest of array items as list.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's what I have so far

```
if (count($all_machines) > 10) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($all_machines as $machine) {
        echo '<li>' . $machine['name'] . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo "No machines";
}
```

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `foreach` you will iterate over all items of the array, I suggest using `for` here instead.

```
if (count($all_machines) > 10) {
    echo '<ul>';
    for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        echo '<li>'.$all_machines[$i]['name'].'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

And if you want to access the other values as well, it could be done like this

```
$count = count($all_machines);
if ($count > 10) {
    echo '<ul>';
    for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {//first 10 elements
        echo '<li>'.$all_machines[$i]['name'].'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    for ($i=10; $i<$count; $i++) {//all other elements
        //do something with $all_machines[$i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)** to get the first 10 elements in the array, allowing you to still use `foreach`.

```
// number of items to display
$display_threshold = 10;

if (count($all_machines) > $display_threshold) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach(array_slice($all_machines, 0, $display_threshold) as $machine)
        echo '<li>' . $machine['name'] . '</li>';

    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'No machines';
}
```